# array push in the async function is not assigned to the external variable

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I want to fetch data with API. `Fecth` is my utils, the get API data. It working the only array so I used the fetch function in the javascript the sample object below. My utils is not supported object.

The problem I'm having is not related to utils. The problem is `array push` in async function.

Array push is not working the map function outside :(

But, is working in the map function :)

What should I do to run outside?

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import Fetch from '@/utils/fetch';

async function allPosts(req, res) {
  const myPostsAll = await Fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_USERNAME}`);

    const posts = [];

    myPostsAll.map(async (item) => {
        const { id } = item;
        const myPostRes = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/${id}`);
        const myPost = await myPostRes.json();

        const { title, description, cover_image, body_html } = myPost;

        posts.push({
            id: id.toString(),
            title,
            thumbnail: cover_image,
            description,
            content: body_html,
        });

        // It's work
        console.log(posts);
    });

    // It's not work
    console.log(posts);
}
```

Comment: I have reviewed this, but I don't understand if I need to use `superagent` or not?

Comment: I have no idea what `superagent` is. But your code displays a very common misunderstanding of asynchronous code - it's not clear what your aim is but by reading the top answers to the linked question you should get some good ideas.

Comment: You are misusing `.map()` here. `.map()` is for transforming one array into another array. If you just want side-effects, use `for..of`, but there is a way to use `.map()` effectively here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to utilize `Promise.all`:

```js
async function allPosts(req, res) {
    const myPostsAll = await Fetch(`...`);
  
    // use `Array.map` to create an array of
    // `Promise`s, then pass that array as an argument
    // to `Promise.all` which will wait for all 
    // `Promise`s to resolve and return an array of objects
    const posts = await Promise.all(
      myPostsAll.map(async (item) => {
        const { id } = item;
        const myPostRes = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/${id}`);
        const myPost = await myPostRes.json();
        const { title, description, cover_image, body_html } = myPost;

        return {
          id: id.toString(),
          title,
          description,
          thumbnail: cover_image,
          content: body_html,
        }
      })
    );
    console.log(posts);
}
```

Also, the reason why your current solution doesn't work is because there's nothing in your code that says to wait for `myPostsAll` to finish before calling `console.log(posts)` at the end of your function outside of the callback of the `Array.map` function:

```js
async function test() {
  const posts = [];
  
  // this is asynchronous, so it won't "wait"
  // to finish before moving to the next statement,
  // unless you apply the solution above with `Promise.all`
  // and `await`
  myPostsAll.map(async () => {
    const myPostRes = await fetch(`...`);
    posts.push(...);
  })

  // gets called prior to `myPostsAll.map` completing
  console.log("posts", posts);
}
```

References:

- [Promise.all - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I couldn't understand how to use this in async functions.
It's worked, thanks for your experiences and help. :)

Comment: @YasinATEŞ see the edit for more explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
import Fetch from '@/utils/fetch';

async function allPosts(req, res) {
  const myPostsAll = await Fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_USERNAME}`);

    

    const posts=myPostsAll.map(async (item) => {
        const { id } = item;
        const myPostRes = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/${id}`);
        const myPost = await myPostRes.json();

        const { title, description, cover_image, body_html } = myPost;

        return {
            id: id.toString(),
            title:title,
            thumbnail: cover_image,
            description,
            content: body_html}
        

        
    });



    // It's not work
    console.log(posts);
}
```